# Exact term search for PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I have been looking at the viwer.js file for days and cannot find the regular expression that allows not exact phrase searching. EX you search for John and you get hits for Johnny. Can anyone direct me to the piece of code that does this. I want to change it to match the exact phrase passed in the URL.

Comment: be careful since text extraction is not exact science (per spec)

Comment: I know, but for my use case I have already set up all the leg work on the back end. I just need the results pdf.js finds to be the same as mine. Hence the changing of the query I asked about. Where is it letting partial matches? A search for John gives Johnny which is not correct.

Comment: Crossposts https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8675 and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8674

Comment: Thanks, that's actually my two posts. Now I am having trouble with the extra spaces inserted into some of the divs. Tried to mess around with the whitespace reg ex function to try and strip multiple white spaces into one, but it broke the mapping.

Comment: Yes, that's not a simple problem. You need to track of what you are stripping out. Modify the search to not use regex and use primitive/naive text search algorithms to find what you want.